# Java null behaviour in array

Tags: java, arrays

say i have a class type and I have to declare an array to store this type. E.g.:

```
MyType[] t = new MyType[5]
```

This means I allocate 5 cells to store items of MyType. And inside my program let's say I added 2 MyType items (dynamically)

```
t[0] = new MyType(..);
t[1] = new MyType(..);
```

If i want to find out how many items are actually filled,

```
int count=0;
for(int j =0; j<t.length ; j++){
   if ( t[j] != null ){
      ++count;
   }
}
```

Is testing for null the correct way ? as i couldn't seem to increment count. count is always 0. Also, length() shows the size of the array which is 5. Is there some method to show the count of actual filled items? thanks

Comment: Please post a complete example that reproduces this.

Comment: The code you've given won't even compile, because you've got `length()` instead of `length`.

Comment: @JonSkeet, yes, just typo.

Comment: Yes, but if *that's* a typo, then what else might you have changed from your real code? Basically, we can't trust that the code you've posted is the code that is causing a problem, which makes it relatively pointless. As Sotirios says, please post a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, actually its quite long. Anyways, all i am asking is the concept. How to test and get the count of  actual filled array items, not counting those that hasn't filled. Java array.length gives the actual size of the array , no matter if its filled or not, right?

Comment: Are you only allowed to use array or can you use any collection?

Comment: @JohnSnow, i just want to get the basic concept on primitive arrays first. thanks.

Comment: @dorothy: make a simple, short, self-contained program that reproduces this. You'll see that the count will be incremented, and that the problem in your real code is thus elsewhere.

Comment: Well your full code may be quite long, but you should try to isolate the problem. The code you've got it fine apart from the typo, so if it's not working then something else must be wrong - and we can't tell without a way of reproducing the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ok i will try to reproduce. But in the meantime, can anyone just advice, let's say forget the count for a while. Is !=null correct for testing an array of a certain type to see how many cells is already filled with that type. ? Just a yes or no will do. thanks

Comment: @dorothy: `!= null` is a test for a reference, and that's fine - it doesn't matter whether the reference is obtained from an array or not. Yes, it should work.

Comment: The answer to your question is yes

Comment: @JonSkeet, thanks. I will try some more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is no .length() method on arrays.  It's a property that you access as

```
for(int j =0; j<t.length ; j++){
   if ( t[j] != null ){
      ++count;
   }
}
```

As for whether this is the only way, I think it is.  You can maybe find utilities like the Apache Commons Collections, but they will still ultimately do the same thing: iterate over the array and check each item.

This is because the term `filled` you use really has nothing to do with the array, rather, it just changes the nth element from being a reference to null to being a reference to something else.  In other worse, an array with 5 null elements and an array with 5 non-null elements are both length 5.

If this is a way to get a variable-size array where length is how many things you have added, then you may want to consider `ArrayList`.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

You can use it as such:

```
List<MyType> t = new ArrayList<MyType>(5);

t.add(new MyType(..));
t.add(new MyType(..));

int count = t.size();  // returns 2
```

Comment: thanks. that's what i needed, but how to do it on primitive arrays without any collections? thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
Below code returns the filled count. 

package com.type;

public class MyType {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public MyType(int id,String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public static void main(String a[]){
        MyType[] t = new MyType[5];
        t[0] = new MyType(1,"Check1");
        t[1] = new MyType(2,"Check2");

        int count=0;
        for(int j =0; j<t.length ; j++){
           if ( t[j] != null ){
              ++count;
           }
        }       
        System.out.println(">>"+count); // Count is 2
        System.out.println(">>"+t.length); // Length is 5   
    }   
}
```